# Poorly written questions that get answers

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

There are various questions -and I think that the number is increasing as of late- in which the authors do not provide the code that they tried and failed and they do not give any description of what the precise issue they are facing is.

What's more to that, in most cases they also cannot be bothered enough to provide a detailed description of the question from the purely mathematical/physical/whatever point of view. They don't even give the expected result that they should derive using Mathematica.

Still there are some people who are willing to try and provide codes in these cases.

The above seems to be in contradiction with the spirit of the site. By "the above" I mean both the way of phrasing a question and providing an answer to these cases.

**Question: is there anything we could do about it? In principle, I do not like downvoting answers, let alone right answers, but are there any other alternatives?**

Comment: good question,. I think the policy if the question is asking for answer without enough information to answer it, is to vote to close it using the reason **Needs clarity or details** choice in the close menu. If 4 more people agree, it will be closed until the person adds the clarify or the missing information. For an example, someone just now posted question asking how to plot solution to pde in some coordinate system but they did not provide the actual code to generate the solution which makes it hard to answer.  This will be good candidate to close for this reason.

Comment: @Nasser yes, precisely this kind of questions. There's another one for inverting a function that does not even give the mathematical result that was expected. Thanks for your input. I guess my question was more on the side of how to persuade users to NOT answer these questions other than down-voting -which I do not like. But I don't think there are many alternatives. Btw, I tried for the ten alternatives yesterday but it got very difficult after a certain point :)

Comment: I have a lot of ambivalence here. My "solution" is to try to bias toward empathy. People don't know what they don't know. They may feel intimidated or just overwhelmed. While it often _seems_ that they haven't really tried anything to solve their problem before posting questions, I don't really know that's the case. If the original poster seems cooperative when prompted to "please post your expected result" or "please post the code you've tried" or whatever, then I'm willing to try to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: @lericr If they — I assume you mean the askers not the answerers — have been cooperative, then presumably the question has been revised and is no longer poorly written, no? Exceptions: Sometimes, the asker doesn't understand — the question, the subject matter, Mma lingo, or more typically English — and I've posted an answer to show what I think they mean, when it seems discussion cannot efficiently resolve the ambiguities. Sometimes I misread a question and get a clear interpretation in my head without noticing the question was obscure. (Sometimes my interpretation is wrong, too.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm aligned with all of that.

Comment: I can see the point that @lericr is making and there is definitely truth to that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 also gives valuable arguments and a resilient approach to the matter. My concern has to do more with the situation where people present a poorly written post, they don't care to provide any clarifications, and it is quite clear that there's no effort made. There are a couple of recent examples. On the other hand, I guess no one can really be sure about that.

Comment: I'm fairly new here, so apologies if there are cultural aspects that I don't understand. With tha said, what I'm struggling with is understanding whether there's an actual problem here and then whether the solution requires a formal process. Let's say we see a "bad" post. We ask for clarification. If we get it, great, we can make progress. If we don't, then the questioner never gets an answer, and that is just an example of natural consequences. Seems like a sort of self-correcting process already. Obviously, if any code of conduct has been violated, the post should just be removed.

Comment: @lericr sorry for my super-delayed response. I am not sure if we can call it a problem. First we need to determine what a problem is for this site. I made a general observation based on recent posts. For example, you can find today's questions that it's very obvious that the person who posted never bothered with the most basic aspects of documentation. It's like they are expecting extended tutorial on the basics, then the intermediate and then the advanced aspects. Half a step away from asking Mathematica to prepare breakfast and morning coffee. \

Comment: No worries about delay. I’m not confident that I should even be butting in!

Comment: @lericr of course you should. this was supposed to be for general discussion. all comments are very welcome :-)